# Kubernetes kustomize command giving error when we specify base manifest files in kustomization.yaml file under resources section

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

I am trying to build manifest file for specific environment example:- test and I want to re-use base manifest files as mentioned below.

k8s/kustomize/overlays/test/kustomization.yaml

```
commonLabels:
  variant: test
  app: test-app
resources:
- ../../base/deployment.yaml
- ../../base/service.yaml
- ../../base/configmap.yaml
- ../../base/secret.yaml
- namespace.yaml
namespace: app-test
patchesStrategicMerge:
- secret.yaml
- configmap.yaml
```

But I got below error when I run the command - kustomize build k8s/kustomize/overlay/test

```
2020/02/19 16:04:36 got file 'deployment.yaml', but 'path/k8s/kustomize/base/deployment.yaml' must be a directory to be a root
Error: accumulating resources: accumulating resources from '../../base/deployment.yaml': security; file 'path/k8s/kustomize/base/deployment.yaml' is not in or below 'path/k8s/kustomize/overlay/test'
```

```
P.S: kustomize version is - Version: {KustomizeVersion:3.2.0 GitCommit:a3103f1e62ddb5b696daa3fd359bb6f2e8333b49 BuildDate:2019-09-18T18:31:04+01:00 GoOs:darwin GoArch:amd64}
```

I am new to kubernetes and kustomize. Could Please help me ?

Comment: Did you use [bases](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/docs/glossary.md#base)? Why you use kustomize build k8s/kustomize/overlay/test when your resources directory is ../../base? Could you fix it and let me know if it works then? If it's not could you show me your file structure, like for example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize#2-create-variants-using-overlays).

Comment: FYI, the documentation says that "the bases field was deprecated in v2.1.0"

Answer (score 23):

Kustomize doesn't allow you to directly include resource files that are not in the same directory or a subdirectory of where your kustomization.yml file is located.

The usual way to use a base in your overlay is to add a kustomization.yml file in the base and include the base directory in the kustomization.yml of your overlay. For example:

`k8s/kustomize/base/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
- configmap.yaml
- secret.yaml
```

and in `k8s/kustomize/overlays/test/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
resources:
- ../../base
- namespace.yaml

namespace: app-test

commonLabels:
  variant: test
  app: test-app

patchesStrategicMerge:
- secret.yaml
- configmap.yaml
```

Comment: As noted in the answer below, this answer is incorrect. Kustomize uses go-getter (hashicorp) under the hood. Any git repos should work if noted properly.

Comment: @RobertSmith I think it still applies. See: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/pull/700 and https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/865 You are not allowed to load a resource file in a directory that is not bellow the root. You are allowed to load kustomization file from wherever you want. This is not related to go-getter but kustomize logic.

Comment: Awesome answer. Clearly explained the problem and solution. Works in 2023 June

Comment: kustomization file and deployment file and service file should be under the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this restriction as follows:

```
kustomize build --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something change because the following example does that the question was trying to do: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/resource/

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- myNamespace.yaml
- sub-dir/some-deployment.yaml
- ../../commonbase
- github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/examples/multibases?ref=v1.0.6
- deployment.yaml
- github.com/kubernets-sigs/kustomize/examples/helloWorld?ref=test-branch
```

Comment: I guess this example loads a kustomize file in the ../../commonbase folder and from there resources which are in the same folder or below.

Comment: The mentioned url has changed to https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/resource/