# How using Kustomize partially change values in overlay

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I'm looking for an elegant solution for handling different values of helm packages on the overlay level:

- We have a base folder and, overlay  folders stg and prod corresponding to environments
- I would like to use a helm chart with a long list of values.

  - Part of those values are the same for all environments - common values.
  - Part of those values are different in each environment.

I want to have a value file with common values and a file with additional environment-specific values.

The goal here is to avoid copy-paste common values in each directory.

What I already tried:

1. Have `common_config.yaml` in `/base/common_config.yaml` and in `/stg/kustomize.yaml` set in `helmCharts` field `valuesFile` to `../base/common_config.yaml` but it will fail when `--load-restrictor` is enabled (which is the default).
2. Use `HelmChartInflationGenerator` on base kustomize and use patching on this resource to add custom value files - but this has the same issue as above.
3. I'm aware that I can render helm on the base image and then use patching to change things - the issue is that it requires changing many many fields and is not maintainable.

Perhaps there is a better way to handle such scenarios.

Comment: It seems like you would just need to `helm install -f common_config.yaml -f preprod_env.yaml ...` to provide the multiple values files to Helm; how is Kustomize involved?

Comment: We don't use Helm CLI, we use `kubectl kustomize test --enable-helm` and use `helmCharts` section of kustomize.yaml, see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md

Answer (score 1):

> We don't use Helm CLI, we use `kubectl kustomize test --enable-helm` and use [`helmCharts` section of `kustomize.yaml`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md)

Given that you are using [Kustomize's `helmCharts`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/helmcharts/) and you want to avoid duplication of common values across different environments, you might consider:

- storing your common configuration in a YAML file that will be used as the base values for the Helm chart.
- creating, for each environment (e.g., staging, production), overlay directories that include additional, environment-specific values.
- specifying, in each overlay's `kustomization.yaml`, the common values file and the environment-specific values file. That will allow Kustomize to merge these values when generating the final configuration for the Helm chart.

That is inspired from "[Generate Kubernetes Manifests with Helm Charts using Kustomize](https://medium.com/@tharukam/generate-kubernetes-manifests-with-helm-charts-using-kustomize-2f82ab5c5f11)" from [Tharuka Mannapperuma](https://lk.linkedin.com/in/tharukamannapperuma).

Assuming a project structure similar to this:

```bash
project/
│
├── base/
│   └── common_values.yaml
│
├── overlays/
│   ├── stg/
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── stg_values.yaml
│   └── prod/
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│       └── prod_values.yaml
```

You would have:

- `common_values.yaml`, for the values that common across all environments.
- overlay kustomizations with:

  - `stg/kustomization.yaml`:

    ````
    ```yaml
    resources:
    - ../../base/common_values.yaml
    helmCharts:
    - name: your-helm-chart
        releaseName: chart-release-stg
        valuesFile: stg_values.yaml
    ```
    ````
  - `prod/kustomization.yaml`:

    ````
    ```yaml
    resources:
    - ../../base/common_values.yaml
    helmCharts:
    - name: your-helm-chart
        releaseName: chart-release-prod
        valuesFile: prod_values.yaml
    ```
    ````

Kustomize will use the values from `common_values.yaml` as the base and merge them with the values specified in `stg_values.yaml` or `prod_values.yaml` for the respective environments. That is achieved through the `valuesFile` field in the `helmCharts` section of the overlay `kustomization.yaml`. See [`HelmChartInflationGenerator`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_helmchartinflationgenerator_).

When using `kubectl kustomize`, the `--load-restrictor` flag can prevent loading files from outside the kustomization root.

Here, your project is structured in a way where the common values file is always within the kustomization root of each environment.

When you run `kubectl kustomize overlays/stg` or `kubectl kustomize overlays/prod` from the `project` directory, the `project` directory becomes the root for the kustomization.
As a result, referencing `../../base/common_values.yaml` from the `overlays/stg/kustomization.yaml` or `overlays/prod/kustomization.yaml` is allowed because the `base` directory is within the scope of the kustomization root (`project`).

Comment: I tried that, but when I put `- ../../base/common_values.yaml` under `resources`, it is failing because of `is not in or below: ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843389/3850519

Comment: @mjpolak Even when done from the `project` directory? `../../base` should be under `project`

Comment: Yes, I recreated the same structure as in your answer.

Comment: @mjpolak I understand you have created the same structure, but did you execute the `kubectl kustomize` command from the root folder, the `project` one? And, for testing, with ` --loadRestriction none`, as described in [PR 995](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/pull/995#issuecomment-490981389).